# Django sql error in view but not via admin

Tags: python, sql, django, model

I'm getting an `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'` error. When I debug my code in my update_account function I can see that instance.amount is `<class 'float'>` and a.balance is `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>` so the error makes sense. Now if I were to add `Transaction(user=id, type='deposit', description='Venmo inc', amount=200.00)` manually in my Admin page the code does not throw an error. Both types are `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`. Why does adding a transaction via my Admin work but adding a transaction through my view throw an error? And how can I handle this error?

Models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=500, decimal_places=2)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Transaction)
def update_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user = instance.user
        a = Account.objects.get(user=user)
        #error occurs here
        a.balance = instance.amount + a.balance 
        a.save()
```

View:

```
def transaction(request):
    id = request.user.id
    t = Transaction(user=id, type='deposit', description='Venmo inc', amount=200.00)
    t.save()
    return HttpResponse('Transaction Complete')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely because the django admin knows the type of the database field and does internal conversion. Your view is not as smart, you need to coerce the float to decimal

```py
from decimal import Decimal

# Quick and dirty hack
def transaction(request):
    id = request.user.id
    t = Transaction(user=id, type='deposit', description='Venmo inc', amount=Decimal(200.00))
    t.save()
    return HttpResponse('Transaction Complete')
```

A better way to do this would be to check the amount is a float in the models save() method and convert it if it isn't.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation and quick fix.